# How to open stackoverflow dump data?

Tags: database, file-extension

The dump file(s) which I have received are in the following format :

- stackoverflow.com.7z.001
- stackoverflow.com.7z.002
- ...
- stackoverflow.com.7z.015

Can somebody tell me how to open these files?

I am doing a project on Data Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) to unzip it. The file format is 7-zip extension